# Why won't Facebook accept the URL of my website in the About section of our Facebook page?

Tags: facebook

We are a legitimate company with an established website, but when I go to enter our website (https://www.oatmama.com) into the appropriate field in our About section on our Facebook page, it responds with an error message: "The website URL you provided is invalid. Please enter a correct URL and try again."

Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you mind to report a bug if this problem still persist? https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/trending/

Comment: same problem here, any suggestion actually?

Answer (score 3):

You might try running your website through the Facebook Debugger:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

This tool was built to help to identify any errors that Facebook is reading from your website, and help provide information on what needs to be fixed to unblock your link.

From there, you can get help from your developers team or from the Facebook Developers team to make your website compliant and help our systems detect it as safe. Click the link below and select "Get Started" to open a support ticket with the Facebook Developers team (this option may not be available for all websites):

https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an upcoming/beta plugin? Some WordPress upcoming/beta plugins return 503 error. If you are using a plugin, disable it and try again.

It works well for me.

Comment: You are might right. But I think the error message 'The website URL you provided is invalid. Please enter a correct URL and try again' does not look like a 503 error message.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that one reason for the *"The website URL you provided is not valid. Please enter a correct URL and try again."* error may occur because the URL is already being used by another Facebook page –possibly a forgotten page, previous page, or an unofficial, unverified page that was created by someone else. It may also be a typo on another Facebook page with a similar URL, *e.g., www.spellingerror.com and www.spellingrror.com*

I can't say this is definitely causing the issue, but it may be in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be answering the actual question, but this is the top result for my own problem.
I've been having a similar issue with facebook for a few times now appearing out of the blue.

Facebook doesn't really give any information about what's actually causing the issue which leaves me without any clue on what to do every time.

**Update July 16th 2023**

It happened to me again. The original answer below didn't fix it for good. This time I had been trying the "URL sharing debugger tool" for about 10 minutes. Tried a bunch of things but what finally made it (this time), was to change https:// to http://. It'll probably work for a few days/weeks/months, who knows.

**Original answer**

After about an hour of trying almost anything with an absolutely valid and working URL, I went to Cloudflare, made a "Configuration Rule" for my /privacy-policy.html page that would disable browser integrity check. It worked immediately after.